# Facilitate JSON array creation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am building an app where clients have to send JSON arrays, but as this is always difficult, I would like to make their life easier, by sending me the array data key by key.
Is it possible in javascript (node.js) to transform this kind of array :

```
{
   "address.town" : "Paris, London, New-York",
   "address.name" : "Home1, Home2, Home3",
   "store" : "Carrefour",
   "address.street" :"Rue de la Paix, Piccadilly, 5th avenue",
   "client.lastName" : "Sinclar, Bob"
}
```

into this :

```
{
"address" :[
        {"town" : "Paris", "name":"Home1", "street" : "Rue de la Paix"},
        {"town" : "London", "name":"Home2", "street" : "Piccadilly"},
        {"town" : "New-York", "name":"Home3", "street" : "5th avenue"}
],
"store" : "Carrefour",
"client" : [
        {"lastName" : "Sinclar"},
        {"lastName" : "Bob"}
]
}
```

I am a beginner in javascript and any help would be much appreciated ! :)

Comment: What you're suggesting is *much* harder than sending the 2nd array in the first place.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: That starting format is terrible. Tokenized strings are not reliable, especially when it comes to a dataset as wildly untamable as postal addresses. Whoever is sending you that data, that person needs to come to their senses. You cannot reliably un-mangle the data they have mangled. You may as well try to extract whole fruits from an already-blended fruit smoothie.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer : can you think of an easier way to create a JSON array from multiple lists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code will exactly generate what you need as far as the input keys do not need to get more nested than what you have provided in the example.

you can reuse the convert function for your updated data;

```js
const data = {
"address.town" : "Paris, London, New-York",
"address.name" : "Home1, Home2, Home3",
"store" : "Carrefour",
"address.street" :"Rue de la Paix, Piccadilly, 5th avenue",
"client.lastName" : "Sinclar, Bob"
}

function convert(data){
    const keys = Object.keys(data);

    const mappedKeys = Object.keys(data).map(key => key.split("."));

    const targetKeys = [...new Set(mappedKeys.map(key => key[0]))];

    const target = {};

    Object.entries(data).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        const keys = k.split(".");
        const values = v.split(", ");
        if (keys.length === 1) {
            Object.assign(target, { [k]: v })
            return;
        }
        if (!target[keys[0]]) {
            target[keys[0]] = values.map(_ => ({}));
        }
        values.forEach((val, idx) => {
            target[keys[0]][idx][keys[1]] = val;
        })
    })
    return target;
}

convert(data);
```

Comment: @EF3178 you're welcome. by the way, the comments section in stackOverflow is not considered for compliments which do not add new information; instead, you can upvote the answer and pay it forward. see: [How to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = {
  'address.town': 'Paris, London, New-York',
  'address.name': 'Home1, Home2, Home3',
  store: 'Carrefour',
  'address.street': 'Rue de la Paix, Piccadilly, 5th avenue',
  'client.lastName': 'Sinclar, Bob',
};

const getKeyValueMap = (values, key, existingValues) => {
  return values.reduce((list, value, index) => {
    return list.concat({ ...existingValues[index], [key]: value });
  }, []);
};

const formatInput = (input) => {
  const obj = {};
  for (const key in input) {
    const values = input[key].split(',');
    const [k1, k2] = key.split('.');
    obj[k1] = (!obj[k1] && k2) ? [] : obj[k1];
    obj[k1] = k2 ? getKeyValueMap(values, k2, obj[k1]) : values[0]
  }
  return obj;
};

console.log(formatInput(input));
```

Comment: consider adding an explanation to the code so its better for us to understand it